Efficient Build Triggering in TeamCity with Accurate Pull Request Status in GitHub for Monolithic Repositories
I am working with a monolithic repository and using TeamCity for our CI/CD pipeline, with GitHub as our VCS. Our current setup includes a set of builds for each of our apps. I want to configure the system so that only the builds corresponding to the apps affected by a pull request are triggered efficiently.
Currently, I've implemented checkout rules to ensure that only files related to the specific app are checked out. This setup works at the commit level: if commit A affects only App A, the correct builds are triggered. However, if the next commit affects only App B, only the CI builds for App B are triggered.
This behavior is efficient but problematic when the previous commit has failures. If there were failures in commit A and the next commit B passes all checks, the pull request could still contain unresolved errors, even though all checks appear green in GitHub.
To maintain both efficiency and accuracy, we need to ensure that TeamCity either reruns the failed builds for previous commits on every new commit or somehow marks the pull request as incomplete if any prior commit builds failed.
I could use some help to achieve this. Thanks in advance!
